# jQuery.ParseJSON() to include function reference

Tags: jquery, json

I have a callback function within an ASP.NET Web Forms application which I am trying to return some handy JSON to so that the javascript function manage the data. I am able to send back a string of JSON that contains all of my data, but now I am trying to get the following structure:

```
{
 data: dataGoesHere
 function: function(){alert('hello');}
}
```

jQuery.parseJSON works great for the simple case of a string being returned like this:

```
"{\"data\" : \"dataGoesHere\"}"
```

but soon as you try to do something like this

```
"{
   \"data\" : \"dataGoesHere\"
   \"function" function(){alert('hello');}
}"
```

jQuery throws an exception. I am wondering if it is possible to create a string so that jQuery can parse into JSON that will include a function reference that I can call later.

I hope this makes sense. Thank you for your time and responses!

Comment: try passing the function as a string and then do eval on the client

Comment: JSON != JavaScript. JSON is only a subset of JavaScript. Your structure is not JSON.

Comment: @thorn: It appears that OP is attempting to create JSON data but is including invalid content. The first code example is the intended result after parsing.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

That's not valid JSON.
It's rejected by jQuery for security reasons, in order to prevent exactly what you're trying to do.

Instead, you can just call `eval`, to interpret it as a Javascript literal.
Note that you'll need to wrap it in parentheses to make sure that it's parsed as an expression and not a block.

Comment: ...and tell jQuery to expect `text` and not `json` as the data type sent from the server.

Comment: within javascript var foo = {bar: function(){alert('hi');}} then calling foo.bar() seems to work fine, so why wouldn't it be valid JSON?

Comment: @Justin: JSON is a **subset** of Javascript.  They're not the same.  JSON doesn't support function literals (or calls).  http://json.org/

Comment: Awesome, that answers my question. Thank you for your input! My mistake for not checking into more details of javascript vs JSON. Thanks again!

Answer (score 0):

You could set up it up as valid JSON and use `eval`.

Edit: 
`j = jQuery.parseJSON("{\"data\":\"DataGoesHere\",\"function\":\"{alert('test');}\"}");`

`eval(j.function)`

Comment: Valid JSON cannot include a function literal, hence your suggestion is not possible.

Answer (score 0):

You can do it like this:

**Example:** http://jsfiddle.net/MvRru/

```
var jsonStr = '{"data" : "dataGoesHere","fn": "{alert(\'hello\');}"}';

var result = $.parseJSON( jsonStr );

result.fn = new Function( result.fn );

result.fn();
```

Comment: @SLaks: You in a hurry? ;o) I'm just demonstrating a way it could be done when using `parseJSON`. You're right that `eval()` will be faster. But then it should always be faster than parsing.

Comment: @patrick: `parseJSON` also calls `eval` (or, to be more precise, `new Function(...)`).  (Unless the browser supports it natively)

Comment: @SLaks: Yes, I know. I'm not sure what your point is. I was agreeing with you that `eval()` is faster than parsing the JSON data.

Comment: @patrick: Parsing the JSON data _uses_ eval (plus a validating Regex).  Yours is only slower because you eval twice.

Comment: @SLaks: Yes (well depending on the implementation), but which do you think is faster, regex plus `eval()`, or just one call to `eval()`?